# Why will this not iterate through the file like I want it to?

Tags: ruby, class, oop, object

It will just output two blank lines to the screen when it should be printing the card id and the balance

I have completely re-written the code.
I have fiddled with that code for an hour

```
class RBC

    def initialize

        @args = ["Create a new card"]
        @functions = ["create_rbc"]

        puts "Do you have an RBC ID yet? Yes(0) No(1)"

        hasrbc = gets.chomp.to_i

        if hasrbc == 1 

            @balance = 5
            create_rbc

        else

            login

        end

    end

    def create_rbc

    puts "\nGenerating your rbc\n\n"
        puts "\nWelcome to your Ruby Binary Card(RBC)!\n\n"
        puts "Your RBC will keep track of your RubyCredits(RC).\n"
        puts "You will get paid RC for work apps, and pay for game apps.\n"
        puts "If you lose track of your RBC ID, you can get a new one.\n"
        puts "Doing this, however, will reset your balance to the default of $5\n\n"
        puts "What is your name? Do first last\n"

        @fullname = gets.chomp
        @card_name = get_name_codec(@fullname)
        @card_cipher = "#{rand(1..9)}#{rand(1..9)}#{rand(1..9)}#{rand(1..9)}#{rand(1..9)}#{rand(1..9)}#{rand(1..9)}#{rand(1..9)}#{rand(1..9)}#{rand(1..9)}"

        @card_id = "#{@card_name} - #{@card_cipher}"
        instance_variable_set("@Id#{@card_cipher}", @balance)

        puts "Write down your RBC ID: #{@card_id}"
        file = File.open("Cards.rbc", "w")
            file.puts @card_id
            file.puts @balance
        end

    end

    def get_name_codec(name)

        names = name.split(" ")

        fname = names[0]
        lname = names[1]

        fchar = fname.split(//)
        fcodec = "#{fchar[0]}#{fchar[1]}"

        name_codec = "#{fcodec}#{lname}"

        return name_codec

    end

    def login
        @found = false
        puts "What is your RBC Id"
        input = gets.chomp
        File.open("Cards.RBC", "r") do |f|
            f.each_line do |line|

                if input == "#{line}"
                    @card_id = line.to_s
                    @found == true
                elsif @found == true
                    @balance = line.to_i
                end


            end

        end

        puts "#{@card_id}#{@balance}"
end

RBC.new
```

Then the Cards.RBC

```
TiLan - 1122632527
5
```

I want it to print the balance and card Id.
It should give me my card id and then the balance like this:
0000...etc
5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input = gets.chomp` removes the newline off the input, but `f.each_line` does not. So `input == "#{line}"` is comparing, for example, `"1234"` with `"1234\n"`.

Chomp the line as well.

```
    input = gets.chomp
    File.open("Cards.RBC", "r") do |f|
        f.each_line do |line|
            line.chomp!
            if input == line
                @card_id = line
                @found == true
            elsif @found == true
                @balance = line.to_i
            end
        end
    end
```

You can debug this sort of thing by printing the values with `p`. This will show them as quoted strings and show any special characters including newlines.

```
p line
p input
```